# Brick issue in JAVA

Tags: java

Given a exercise to do in Java, and haven't got a clue how to do it:

"We want to make a row of bricks that is X inches long, we have a number of small bricks (1 inch long) to be entered by the user, and a number of big bricks (5 inches long) to also be entered by the user. "

I have got as far as determining the length of the goal and then the numbers of each brick (stored as int's), and taking the total length of the amount of bricks given (ie smallbrick * 1, and bigbrick * determine if it possible to make the goal (X inches) using the number of entered bricks.5) and whilst I know what do do in words, I have no idea how to convert this into code

Code Below so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class BrickMan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("How Large is the Goal (In Inches)? "); 
        int goal = kb.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("How Many Big Bricks Do You Have? "); 
        int bgbrk = kb.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("How Many Small Bricks Do You Have? "); 
        int smlbrk = kb.nextInt(); 
        byte smlbrklen = 1; 
        byte bgbrklen = 5; 
        int ttlbgbrk = bgbrklen * bgbrk; 
        int ttlsmlbrk = smlbrklen * smlbrk;
```

Thank you

Comment: try your hand at some code first. we like to see some code ( [SSCCE](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsscce.org%2F&ei=74shVI_jBsSiyATs_YCgCA&usg=AFQjCNFdqWH-Hxu7Vlsk6vBvl9vWtnAdrw&sig2=TH_Cw98BustDOhKkxcJibQ&bvm=bv.75775273,d.aWw) )

Comment: trivially, `X - (min(X % 5, big) * 5) <= small` -> you can, and `resBig = min(X % 5, big); resSmall = X - 5 * resBig;`

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't exist to do your homework for you.

Comment: FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

Given

- #smallBricks
- #largeBricks
- X

Find sb <= smallBricks, lb <= largeBricks such that

```
X == sb * 1 + lb * 5;
```

How would you do that in reality?

- start using as much of the large bricks as possible (because you are evidently lazy too)
- fill out the rest with small bricks

  ```
  int lb = 0;
  int sb = 0;
  int builtLength = 0;
  while (built has room for a large brick) {
      add a large brick
  }
  while (built has room for a small brick) {
      add a small brick
  }
  ```

And then use math. For instance how many large bricks can you use at most?

```
Integer division:    17 / 5 = 3
Integer modulus:     17 % 5 = 2
                     3 * 5 + 2 = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a `<` comparison:

```
int totalLength=kb.nextInt()
int bigBricks = kb.nextInt();
int smallBricks = kb.nextInt();
int lengthOfBricks = bigBricks*5+smallBricks;
if (lengthOfBricks>=totalLength)
    System.out.println("It's long enough");
else
    System.out.println("It's not long enough");
```